# Detect hover with JointJS

Tags: hover, jointjs

I am using JointJS API to draw a rectangle with an embed path inside it.

This path serves as a button, and I would like to make this button visible only when the rectangle is hovered, however I can't figure how to detect hover on a parent element with JointJS... Is there any programmatic way to detect it? Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

I finally found that you simply have to create a custom view in Backbone.js listening to the hover event:

```
var ConstraintElementView = joint.dia.ElementView.extend({
        events: {
            'mouseover': 'mouseovercard'
        },

        mouseovercard: function(evt, x, y) {
            var size = this.model.get('size');
            console.log(size);
        }
    });
```

And then use this view for your paper:

```
var paper = new joint.dia.Paper({
        el: $('#canvas'),
        width: 1200,
        height: 900,
        gridSize: 10,
        model: graph,
        elementView: ConstraintElementView,
        ...
    });
```

Comment: Using custom views is not necessary in JointJS v0.9.3+. `dia.Paper` triggers `cell:mouseover` and `cell:mouseout` events. http://jointjs.com/api#joint.dia.Paper:events

Comment: @Roman I must be doing something wrong because I can't get those events to trigger, whether with `on('all', ...)` or `on('cell:mouseover', ...)`. I looked at the pull request where this was addressed and see that it is in the code, and that they are using the terms `mouseleave` and `mouseenter`, but still can't get them working.

Comment: @Gornitorink Do you know how to send the event up through the Backbone notification mechanism? I'd like to be able to link it with the `cell.on('all', ...)` event listener.